# RESTEasy doesn't recognize custom message body writer

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

My MessageBodyWriter

```
@Provider
@Produces("text/csv")
public class CSVMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<JaxbList>

    public static final String CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER = "Content-Disposition";     
   //$NON-NLS-1$
    private final static HeaderDelegate<ContentDispositionHeader> header = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createHeaderDelegate(ContentDispositionHeader.class);

    public long getSize(JaxbList t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return CsvSerializer.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    public void writeTo(JaxbList t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
                    OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        // set content disposition. This will enable browsers to open excel
        ContentDispositionHeader contentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeader.createContentDispositionHeader(MediaTypeUtils.CSV_TYPE);
        contentDispositionHeader.setFileName("representation"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        httpHeaders.putSingle(CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER, header.toString(contentDispositionHeader));

        Charset charset = Charset.forName(ProviderUtils.getCharset(mediaType));
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, charset);

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
        Iterator<String[]> rows = ((CsvSerializer) t).getEntities();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            printWriter.println(CsvWriter.getCSVRow(rows.next()));
        }
        printWriter.flush();
    }
}
```

My REST Application

```
@Path("app/v3")
@GZIP
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, "text/csv"})
 public class ApplicationREST
```

Extension of Application

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

  private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
  private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

  public JaxRsActivator() {
    singletons.add(new CSVMessageBodyWriter());
    classes.add(ApplicationREST.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    Set<Object> defaults = super.getSingletons();
    singletons.addAll(defaults);
    return singletons;
  }

  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    return classes;
  }
}
```

When I run in debug mode I can hit my JaxRsActivator class, so I know that the providers are being loaded.  However I get the error "Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: net.comp.jaxb.JaxbList of media type: text/csv"

Comment: Is `classes.add(AppREST.class);` a typo? Or do you just forgot to somehow make the ApplicationREST available ?

Comment: thats a typo. its ApplicationREST

Comment: @Cam Sonaris - Can you please post your MessageBodyWriter implementation?

Comment: @GregWhitaker made the edits, however i'm not sure how this is helpful because it doesnt even hit the class

Comment: @Cam Sonaris - Have you tried adding the class to the resteasy.providers context parameter in web.xml?

Comment: @GregWhitaker I have tried and it still can not find it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your code above it would appear that your `CSVMessageBodyWriter` is being called, but it is failing your `isWriteable` check.

Your `isWriteable` check is always going to return false.  You are checking if `JaxbList` is assignable from `CSVSerializer`.  This is always going to fail and your `CSVMessageBodyWriter` will not be deemed able to handle `text/csv`.

Try changing your isWriteable method to the following:

```
public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) 
{
    return true;
}
```

This will serialize all `text/csv` annotated methods.  If you want to constrain it to `JaxbList` then you can do something like this:

```
public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) 
{
    ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) genericType;

    if(paramType.getRawType().equals(JaxbList.class))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Here is a simple working example of configuring a custom `MessageBodyWriter`:

**Application**

```
public class ProductGuideApplication extends Application
{
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public ProductGuideApplication() 
    { 
        singletons.add(new CSVMessageBodyWriter());
        classes.add(FooResource.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons()
    { 
        return singletons;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() 
    {
        return classes;
    }
}
```

**Resource**

```
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource
{
    @GET
    @Produces("text/csv")
    public List<Consumer> getConsumers()
    {
        Consumer consumer1 = new Consumer();
        consumer1.setId("1234");
        consumer1.setGender("Male");

        Consumer consumer2 = new Consumer();
        consumer2.setId("2345");
        consumer2.setGender("Male");

        List<Consumer> consumers = new ArrayList<Consumer>();
        consumers.add(consumer1);
        consumers.add(consumer2);

        return consumers;
    }
}
```

**MessageBodyWriter**

```
@Provider
@Produces("text/csv")
public class CSVMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<List<Consumer>>
{
    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) 
    {
        ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) genericType;

        if(paramType.getRawType().equals(List.class))
        {
            if(paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0].equals(Consumer.class))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(List<Consumer> t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(List<Consumer> t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
            OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException 
    {
        //Write your CSV to entityStream here.
    }
}
```