# Media type to use when returning a resultset from jena in a REST web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, sparql, jena

i have this code and when i run it, it return a"JSON" empty
just the structure of the "JSON".

what is wrong? and what i have to do?

package com.Data;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;

import javax.ws.rs.PUT;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Servicio")

public class Servicio {

```
@Context

private UriInfo context;


public Servicio() {    }

@GET

@Path("/{universidad}")

@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})

public ResultSet getJson(@PathParam("universidad") String universidad) { 

    com.Data.Metodos metodo = new Metodos();

    universidad = universidad.replace(' ', '+');

    String URI = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql/University/country/?"+universidad+"/es/1/=json/";

    String lista[];

    String filtros[];

    String Query = "";

    lista = metodo.get_Cadenas(URI);

    filtros = metodo.elementos(lista);

    Query = metodo.Query(filtros);

    return (metodo.outformat(Query, filtros[0], filtros[4]));   


}

@PUT

@Consumes("application/json")

public void putJson(String content) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your `@Produces` annotation should be the media type(s) you wish to make available to your clients.

You have `application/json` in your example above so I am assuming that you want to return json to your clients.  The problem is that the json serializer is not going to know how to convert `ResultSet` to a json object unless you tell it how to do it.

You need to create a custom `MessageBodyWriter` in order to handle serializing the `ResultSet` object to json.

Take a look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593474/resteasy-doesnt-recognize-custom-message-body-writer/17682414#17682414) for an example of creating and registering a custom `MessageBodyWriter` in JAX-RS.

Comment: thanks friend 
I will review

Comment: The MIME type is application/sparql-results+json.  ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON will write this format.